# Why doesn't the NumPy-C api warn me about failed allocations?

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

I've been writing a Python extension that writes into a `NumPy` array from C. During testing, I noticed that certain very large arrays would generate a `segfault` when I tried to access some of their elements.

Specifically, the last line of the following code segment fails with a `segfault`:

```
    // Size of buffer we will write to
    npy_intp buffer_len_alt = BUFFER_LENGTH;

    //
    PyArray_Descr * dtype;
    dtype = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_BYTE);
    PyObject* column = PyArray_Zeros(1, &buffer_len_alt, dtype, 0);

    //Check that array creation succeeds
    if (column == NULL){
        // This exit point is not reached, so it looks like everything is OK
        return (PyObject *) NULL;
    }

    // Get the array's internal buffer so we can write to it
    output_buffer = PyArray_BYTES((PyArrayObject *)column);

    // Try writing to the buffer
    output_buffer[0] = 'x'; //No segfault
    output_buffer[((int) buffer_len_alt) - 1] = 'x'; // Segfault here
```

I checked and found that the error occurs only when I try to allocate an array of about 3GB (i.e. `BUFFER_LENGTH` is about 3*2^30). It's [not surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier) that an allocation of this size would fail, even if Python is using it's custom allocator. What really concerns me is that `NumPy` **did not raise an error or otherwise indicate that the array creation did not go as planned**.

I have already tried checking `PyArray_ISCONTIGUOUS` on the returned array, and using `PyArray_GETCONTIGUOUS` to ensure it is a single memory segment, but the `segfault` would still occur. `NPY_ARRAY_DEFAULT` creates contiguous arrays, so this shouldn't be necessary anyways.

**Is there some error flag I should be checking? How can I detect/prevent this situation in the future?** Setting `BUFFER_LENGTH` to a smaller value obviously works, but this value is determined at runtime and I would like to know the exact bounds.

---

**EDIT**:

As @DavidW pointed out, the error stems from casting `buffer_len_alt` to an `int`, since `npy_intp` can be a 64-bit number. Replacing the cast to `int` with a cast to 'unsigned long' fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Is this to do with the cast to int (`((int) buffer_len_alt) - 1`), which is probably signed just fails to hold `BUFFER_LENGTH`? (assuming 32 bit ints)

Comment: @DavidW You should make that an answer.  `buffer_len_alt` has type `npy_intp`, which on most platforms is a 64 bit signed integer.  If the `int` type on the platform is 32 bit, then  `(int) buffer_len_alt` will be a negative integer when `buffer_len_alt` is `3*(2**30)`.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the advice! I was able to confirm that this was indeed the problem. If you post the answer I'll be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue (diagnosed in the comments) was actually with the array lookup rather than the allocation of the array.  Your code contained the line

```
output_buffer[((int) buffer_len_alt) - 1] = 'x'
```

When `buffer_len_alt` (approx value 3000000000) was cast to an (32 bit) int (maximum value 2147483647) you ended up with an invalid address, probably a large negative number.

The solution is just to use

```
output_buffer[buffer_len_alt - 1] = 'x'
```

(i.e. I don't see why you should need a cast at all).